# number of char in bash

Tags: bash

in bash calculate line char I did this example bellow but it does not work for me
I try to

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
line=$2
v=0

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "$0 fileName"
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f $file ]
then
    echo "$file not a file"
    exit 2
fi

while read -n 1 c
do
  l=$(echo $c | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])
  [[ "$l" == "a" || "$l" == "e" || "$l" == "i" || "$l" == "o" || "$l" == "u" ]] && (( v++ ))
done < $file


echo "Characters : $(cat $file | wc -c)"
```

I want code to count something like character or anything in the paragraph I give it ?

Comment: Why should I do YOUR homework?

Comment: I have many project and I do a lot of search before I ask and I try hard but I can not know if you do not want it is ok .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to spoonfeed you here and give you the answer. Promise that you'll study it for understanding and not just cut and paste.

You don't need to read the file character by character. That will make is much slower, and harder to determine what line you're on. If you need to do this in just the shell: read the file line by line, and when you're on the right line, there's a parameter expansion that returns the length of the value.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
lineno=$2

# ... validation here ...

nr=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if (( ++nr == lineno )); then
        printf "Line %d from file %s has %d characters" \
            "$lineno" "$file" "${#line}"
        break
    fi
done <"$file"
```

Further reading:

- [3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)
- [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)
- [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

But a pipeline of common tools is simper:

```
sed -n "$lineno {p;q}" "$file" | wc -c      # this will count the newline
# or
awk -v n="$lineno" 'FNR == n {print length($0)}' "$file"
```

Comment: Please feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: @how mark this as the answer please.